# Far off VS Way off (future time)

Tags: grammar, future-time

What's the difference?
Can I say "my birthday is far off" and/or "my birthday is way off"?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The standard idiomatic usage metaphorically conflating *distant in future **time*** with ***spatially*** remote is...

> *My birthday is **a long way off***

We don't actually say *X is **far** off* very often at all for temporally *or* spatially distant things (but *far **away*** is common). And we mostly use *X is **way** off* in the highly metaphoric sense of *a long way from what it **should** be* (as in a completely wrong answer, something very badly adjusted, etc.).

---

Google Ngrams has a 5-word limit on search strings, so I can't directly compare *1: **Christmas is far off,** 2: **Christmas is way off,** 3: **Christmas is a long way off*** because that last sequence is 6 words. But [here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Christmas%20is%20far%20off%2CChristmas%20is%20way%20off%2CChristmas%20is%20a%20long%20way&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CChristmas%20is%20a%20long%20way%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CChristmas%20is%20a%20long%20way%3B%2Cc0) a chart showing no hits at all for the first two, where I removed that final word ***off*** from the last one (which has *lots* of matches; people are always impatient for Xmas!). And I bet every match that it *did* find will actually include that 6th word anyway.